# Will I ever be able to have more space for more units?

Tags: pixel-kingdom

In the beginning of the game, you are only allowed to have 8 units equipped per battle. So, I want to know whether or not the game will eventually let me equip more troops per battle.

Sources (for credibility) would be awesome.